# copy <form>, <div> or <p> data to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a script where there will be a button that, when pressed, all data in a `<form>`, `<div>` or `<p>` should be copied to the system clipboard for further use.

I've tried various things but with no luck. So I was wondering if you guys have a solution in either JS or PHP (if exists).

NOTE: users will be using various browsers

IE7
Google Chrome
FireFox

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy to clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644057/copy-to-clipboard)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Neither PHP (since it's executed server-side) or Javascript can be used to have implement a fully functional `copy to clipboard` feature that will work cross-browsers.

Instead the regular method of solving this is to use a flash object which can handle these kind of situations. The flash object can of course be loaded, and often queried, using javascript.

**Here are two out of many libraries that provide this functionality**:

- **[code.google.com - zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)** (recommended)
- **[zClip - jQuery ZeroClipboard](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/)**